# Can not verify rule set jar

Tags: java, certificate, keytool, jarsigner, jar-signing

Another try to open a message here

My company wants to use the deployment rule set for multiple java versions usage.

Currenly we have 1.6.0_13, 1.7.0_51 and 1.8.0_66
Java 8 is what selected in the System tab of the java control home
User tab consists of java 6, 7 and 8

all the settings in deployment.properties are default and point to correct locations or values

env variables set
java_home ="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin"
path = set to correct locations

The steps i followed are below,

1. create the keystore
   keytool -genkey -dname "cn=drstest, ou=abac, o=mycompany, c=SE" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias testsign -keypass password -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass password -validity 1460
2. downloaded the csr file
   keytool -certreq -alias testsign -file certreq.csr -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass password
3. Used the csr file and sent it to my company's CA for signing.
4. Received two files: cer and p7b files from CA
5. Import CSR reply:
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -file certnew.p7b -alias testsign -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass password
6. Downloaded and added required certificates of the chain in the keystore.
7. created the ruleset.xml
8. created the jar file using jar.exe
   jar.exe -cvf DeploymentRuleSet.jar ruleset.xml
9. signed the jar file the keystore
   jarsigner -keystore mykeystore.jks DeploymentRuleSet.jar testsign
10. added the time stamp
    jarsigner -verbose -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass password -keypass password -tsa http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 DeploymentRuleSet.jar testsign -J-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx.xxx.COM -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
11. Placed the DeploymentRuleSet.jar in the C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment folder

Now when i test using the java control home
Control panel -> Java -> Security tab -> View active deployment rule set ->

i get the message as 
"DeploymentRuleset.jar is invalid"
"Can not verify rule set jar"

I can see my certificate in the "View Certificate details"

Now i have spents so many hrs and have gone through so many webpages, and still dont know why it is invalid.

This is not rocket science, but still i am stuck.

Can some one point out where i am going wrong.

********* i am not sure if there are any steps for cacerts file, if i have missed something for cacerts please guide me*************

Regards

Comment: This question is not answerable without seeing your `ruleset.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

either use an older JDK to sign your DSR jar ... for example the 1.6.0_13 JDK

OR

with your newer JDK add this to your jarsigner command `-tsadigestalg SHA1`

```
jarsigner -tsadigestalg SHA1 -verbose -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass password -keypass password -tsa http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 DeploymentRuleSet.jar testsign -J-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx.xxx.COM -J-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

Oracle mentions something about it in this article

Java SE from 7 Update 76 and Earlier Throws a JARSigningException with Jar Files Signed Using the '-tsa' Option by Versions of Java SE 8u92-b31 and Later(2191197.1)
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2191197.1

Its what worked for me