# Deployment Rule Set in java 1.8 is not working

Tags: internet-explorer, deployment, jarsigner

I am trying to download and Run the applet code in IE browser, it was working in Java 1.5, but I am trying to make it work on Windows 10 with java version 1.8 and IE 11. I have set up the rule in ruleset.xml as below

```
<ruleset version="1.0+">
    <rule>
        <id location="http://localhost/" />
        <action permission="run" />
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

below are the steps followed to create a jar with a self-sign certificate.

1:jar -cvf DeploymentRuleSet.jar ruleset.xml

2:keytool.exe -genkey -alias SelfSigned -keystore "SelfSigned.jks" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -startdate "2000/01/01 00:00:00" -validity 18262

3:keytool.exe -export -file "SelfSigned.cer" -alias SelfSigned -keystore "SelfSigned.jks"

4:jarsigner.exe -keystore "SelfSigned.jks" -signedjar "DeploymentRuleSet.jar" DeploymentRuleSet.jar SelfSigned

5: I have checked, is jar verified with the certificate, it says the jar is verified as below

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -keystore SelfSigned.jks DeploymentRuleSet.jar

s k      151 Wed Feb 20 15:11:44 IST 2019 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         313 Wed Feb 20 15:11:44 IST 2019 META-INF/SELFSIGN.SF
        1337 Wed Feb 20 15:11:44 IST 2019 META-INF/SELFSIGN.RSA
           0 Wed Feb 20 15:03:56 IST 2019 META-INF/
smk      161 Wed Feb 20 15:03:22 IST 2019 ruleset.xml

jar verified.
```

6: I have copied the respective DeploymentRuleSet.jar in the path

```
:C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment
```

7: When I checked in configure java under security tab  it's giving below error:

```
Can not verify self-signed Deployment Rule Set jar
Deployment Rule Set jar is Invalid
```

I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIRnO.png) have attached the screenshot as well

Please Let me know anywhere I am missing any steps, I have spent a couple of days still, I am not able to figure it out.

Advanced thanks for the Help.

Comment: >it was working in Java 1.5

In this scenario, whether the OS version is window 10 and IE browser version is IE 11? If the environment is same (only with the different Java version), the issue is related to the Java 1.8 version, I suggest you could post the problem in the Java developer forum.

[thread 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/548723/java-deployment-rule-set-via-ad-enterprise-ca/559753#559753) and [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156219/can-not-verify-rule-set-jar) contains the similar problem, you could check it.